# Javascript using RegEx to get multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I used the code below to get every 5 lines from an external text file. It works ok when testing with https://regex101.com/ but when running on Javascript the console return just 3 lines
Anyone knows what is the issue, please

It also works if data is included inside the function but doesn't work if loading from local file

```
reader = new FileReader();
if (filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      const regex = /(?:.*\s){1,5}/gm;


      // This one works as expected
      // const str = `    Line 1
      // Line 2
      // Line 3
      // Line 4
      // Line 5
      // Line 1
      // Line 2
      // Line 3
      // Line 4
      // Line 5`;

      //Loading from external file does not work
      const str = e.target.result;
      let m;

      while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
          regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
          console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        });
      }
```

Testing Data:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Result:

```
Found match, group 0: Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: It sounds like the external file contents are not `===` to the `str` that you say works as expected - find the difference, and that'll probably be the answer.

Comment: Do you want every 5th line? Or to split this into an array of arrays, 5 lines per element? Confused about the goal.

Comment: Thanks for asking @christian. My goal is to take the first 5th lines and do some works on that then take the next 5th lines and so on. That would be good if split them into an array which 5 lines per element. Both work for my purpose

Comment: @quanlai I left an answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use regex - I would use `.split()` with `\n` separator, and [this `chunk()` method](https://medium.com/@Dragonza/four-ways-to-chunk-an-array-e19c889eac4) to group them.

```js
const str = `Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10`;

Array.prototype.chunk = function(size) {
  const chunked_arr = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < this.length) {
    chunked_arr.push(this.slice(index, size + index));
    index += size;
  }
  return chunked_arr;
}

const matches = str.split("\n").chunk(5);
console.log(matches);
```